# Hard focus on me and no team support, how to deal with it?

Tags: overwatch

When playing **Mercy on ranked games**, I get focused really hard by the enemy tanks (specially by **Winston** and **D.va**) and my team seems to not care about it most of the times as I play solo and communication at low elo (~2000) doesn't always work as it should.

My main concern is to be **healing our tanks** most of the time and that leads to be playing near the enemies and sometimes being really exposed.

So, is there anything I can do myself to avoid getting killed by enemy tanks that jump onto me?

Comment: Not really. Both Dva and Winston are flanking tanks, their main goal is to try to take out the healers in the back. As Mercy, you're the most defenseless support in the game. If your team doesn't back you up, the only thing you can do to save yourself is try to stay in a position where you can fly away to a far off teammate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While switching to a different character is certainly a valid tactic, there are a few things you can at least try as Mercy before giving up.

Your dash is your main safety valve. Try and be aware of where your teammates are, and who you can dash to to get out of trouble.

It's especially useful to dash to someone at a higher elevation. Mercy's ability to slowly float to the ground lets her stay in the air for quite some time. This could make you a more obvious target if your enemies are paying attention to the skies, but if they're already focusing on you that's not a big deal. It can be very helpful to have a Pharah around, so you can fly up in the air with her.

Also, consider staying back behind most of your allies. If your tank runs off to attack the other team by themselves, that's their mistake. Don't encourage them by following. If every time they back up to the group they get healed, it will give them incentive to group up more.

Comment: Thank you for the extended Mercy hindsight. I don't play her enough to add that kind of info in my answer ^.^

Answer (score 5):

Either dash to a further teamate and if it doesn't keep you safe long enough or you need something else... **swap character**

Overwatch is a game where you should stay light on your feet in all the ways possible, and swapping characters is one of these ways. If your support is being countered by large tanks dashing onto you, 2 other support characters would help you out.

Lucio is able to push back these large tanks and run away with a wall ride.

Zenyatta can discord orb these tanks and do some damage himself. And, with the help of his team, kill the threat.

Comment: "Maining" a character is a bad idea in all the ways possible. The game wasn't released as a free to play for this exact reason.

Comment: There was no indication in the OP that they main Mercy, but your point is valid. Learn the strengths of each character and when it's best to play them.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf that's why I placed this as a comment and not in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the current answers: NEVER focus heal your Tanks as Mercy. This may sound stupid, but in the current metagame, Zenyatta should be healing tanks as you damage boost the main DPS (soldier, mostly widow, zenyatta ... etc).

You may ask *"why damage boost when I can heal so much?"*. The answer is simple: if you are doing more damage than the other team is doing to you, it doesn't matter how much you are healing, you've already won the fight. Which is why if you are playing mercy and you have a Widowmaker, if you aren't pocketing that widow 90% of the time, you are doing something wrong.

This goes for most supports: you need to know who to focus heal, Zen should focus DIVE TANKS, Mercy focus DPS, Lucio focus well...everyone, Moira tanks, etc.

Source... I play for a OWL team as a support (but do no wish to reveal identity, sorry <3)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade! Thanks for your input, I've edited it slightly so it's a little easier to read, if you have any questions about how our site works, check out the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help), or if it isn't answered there, feel free to ask us on our [Meta site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) :-)